# Amsterdam transit with Irish visa

Tags: visas, transit

I have a Iranian passport but I also have the biometrics visa from Ireland as well.
Do I need a visa to have a connection flight from Amsterdam?

Answer (score 1):

Your Irish visa exempts you in any case from the *airport transit* visa requirement.

It does not exempt you from the regular Schengen visa requirement, should your journey require one (e.g. if you have two lay-overs in the Schengen area). Without such a visa, you cannot visit the city during your layover either.